# Convert URL with querystring to "Search Engine Friendly" URL

Tags: php, url, replace, preg-replace, friendly-url

I wondered if it was possible to rewrite a URL so designed for the rewrite wrote in htaccess.

e.g.

I have the URL:   `http://example.com/page.php?page=5&action=something`

But I want to change the URL to: `example.com/page/5/something`

This is just for the href, the htaccess bit is solved.

Comment: Whats stopping you from doing it manually?

Comment: Nothing, just wondered if there was a way of doing it through PHP :)

Comment: I just need to replace ?page= with a '/' basically but even if the page is something different like action

Comment: Any half decent IDE with a search and replace function should handle this with ease.

Comment: You could write a utility function which converted between the plain and "SEF" versions, then if your scheme changed you could update the function and not have to manually change the links again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function rewritelink($link){
    $link = str_replace('.php','', $link);
    $pattern = "/\?[^=]*=/";
    $replacement = '/';
    $link = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $link);
    $pattern = "/\&[^=]*=/";
    $replacement = '/';
    $link = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $link);
    return $link;
}
```